# War deployment issue on Wildfly 13.x. Why?

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I'm new to Wildfly Application Server. Now, I have an application which is running fine on Wildfly 9.x but when I'm trying to deploy that project on Wildfly 13.x. it's giving me an error given below.

This is the exception after deploying :

```
16:09:18,173 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class com.ver.dataextraction.security.services.helper.LoginHelper in Module "deployment.DataExtraction.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/ver/dataextraction/security/services/helper/LoginHelper (Module "deployment.DataExtraction.war" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:839)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:519)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:143)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

16:09:18,175 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."DataExtraction.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."DataExtraction.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "DataExtraction.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:150)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.ver.dataextraction.security.services.LoginServiceBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.DataExtraction.war" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:143)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/ver/dataextraction/security/services/helper/LoginHelper (Module "deployment.DataExtraction.war" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:839)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:519)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    ... 13 more

16:09:18,225 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.14.Final}
16:09:18,226 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
16:09:18,227 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
16:09:18,252 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.2.Final}
16:09:19,222 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "DataExtraction.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"DataExtraction.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"DataExtraction.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.ver.dataextraction.security.services.LoginServiceBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.DataExtraction.war\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/ver/dataextraction/security/services/helper/LoginHelper (Module \"deployment.DataExtraction.war\" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder"}}
16:09:19,231 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "DataExtraction.war" (runtime-name : "DataExtraction.war")
16:09:19,232 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."DataExtraction.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "DataExtraction.war"

16:09:19,261 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
16:09:19,263 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
16:09:19,263 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
16:09:19,263 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 13.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 5.0.0.Final) started (with errors) in 4038ms - Started 359 of 582 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 334 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
16:09:54,324 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'DataExtraction.war#Document'
16:09:54,326 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/MetadataExtractionDS]
16:09:54,330 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment DataExtraction.war (runtime-name: DataExtraction.war) in 7ms
16:09:54,332 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "DataExtraction.war" (runtime-name: "DataExtraction.war")
16:09:54,548 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for Document
16:09:54,549 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0091: -ds.xml file deployments are deprecated. Support may be removed in a future version.
16:09:54,606 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'DataExtraction.war#Document'
16:09:54,606 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: Document
    ...]
16:09:54,611 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/MetadataExtractionDS]
16:09:54,615 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-3) Failed to define class com.ver.dataextraction.security.services.helper.LoginHelper in Module "deployment.DataExtraction.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/ver/dataextraction/security/services/helper/LoginHelper (Module "deployment.DataExtraction.war" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:839)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:519)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:143)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

16:09:54,615 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."DataExtraction.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."DataExtraction.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "DataExtraction.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:150)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.ver.dataextraction.security.services.LoginServiceBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.DataExtraction.war" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:143)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/ver/dataextraction/security/services/helper/LoginHelper (Module "deployment.DataExtraction.war" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:839)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:519)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    ... 13 more

16:09:55,586 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"DataExtraction.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"DataExtraction.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.ver.dataextraction.security.services.LoginServiceBean with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.DataExtraction.war\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/ver/dataextraction/security/services/helper/LoginHelper (Module \"deployment.DataExtraction.war\" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder"}}
16:09:55,634 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "DataExtraction.war" with deployment "DataExtraction.war"
16:09:55,635 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."DataExtraction.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "DataExtraction.war"
```

**Why the issue is coming and how can I solve this ?**

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/ver/dataextraction/security/services/helper/LoginHelper you should take a look around this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://dzone.com/articles/java-classnotfoundexception-vs-noclassdeffounderro) you have a good explanation about a NoClassDefFoundError.

So basically the class `org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder`cannot be found in your `DataExtraction.war`. The missing class is used inside `com/ver/dataextraction/security/services/helper/LoginHelper`.

So adding the missing class (I think its located in something like spring-security-core-4.2.10.RELEASE.jar) to your `DataExtraction.war` should fix the Problem.

At least at compile time the dependency is present, otherwise you should not be able to create the `DataExtraction.war`. If you use maven, maybe the dependency is set to provided.